# replaceAll without replace html tags JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
var Text= "iam <strong>strong</strong>";
var search="strong";


var strongAndText='<strong>'+search+'</strong>';
var ReplaceText = Text.replaceAll(search,strongAndText);
Text = ReplaceText;
```

output screen
`iam <strong>strongstrong>`

output HTML
`iam &lt;<strong>strong</strong>&gt;<strong>strong</strong><!--<strong-->strong&gt;`

I don't want to replace the tags HTML like `<strong>&&</strong>`
I want the out stay the same or can be like that `<strong><strong>strong</strong></strong>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5923139

Comment: Yo are absolutely not the first person ever facing such a problem … so please do a bit of basic research before you ask. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+replace+text+but+not+in+tags

Comment: Did you try using regex?

Comment: @guyaloni read the SO articles that are right above your comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could replace `<strong>` and `</strong>` to anything lik `<$NOT$S$TRON$>` and `</$NOT$S$TRON$>` then replace your "strong" and then replace your `<$NOT$S$TRON$>`'s back.

Comment: What if the text is "<strong>strong</ strong>"? Or if "$NOT" needs to be replaced?

Comment: In this case you should use regex. But thats not the question.

Comment: I think the question uses the current text as illustration, not as *the only* thing that will ever be replaced. So a solution should likely take that as a starting point.